# Is it possible to fake user inputs not in testing

Tags: python, user-input, stringio

I have developed a game that basically moves on a Cartesian coordinate system. Now to spare you all having to read through all the code I wrote( simply because I am still new and its very bad haha)I will simply ask the question. I read somewhere that you can fake user input by modifying the StringIO and tried a few things but I dont really understand how you manipulate it.I have added a command that captures all the movement commands and i want to replay all the movements that have been passed to the user input. So what i want to do is to be able to make a replay function that simply passes the recorded moves in as input to repeat those movements instead of having to type them in again.

Comment: How do you capture the use input?

Comment: I have a function  user_commands that takes the users input and returns it

Comment: **How** does it take the input? `input()`?

Comment: oh sorry. yes just your standard input user_command = input("some text: ")